# Flex executing a function on another view

Tags: apache-flex, components, swipe

I have a headerbar.mxml that is displayed when user swipes_down in my app. The headerbar.mxml contains a button component I want to run an erase() in the main application window. The main application is a drawing app that contains an erase(). I just don't know how to call a function from another mxml view file. I thought it would be something like click="{mainwindow.drawPanel.erase()}";

**EDIT:**

```
protected function onColorChange(event:List):void{
                appHome.drawArea.erase();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a function in another view (AKA Component) It depends largely on the architecture.  It sounds like you want to run a function in your parent.  In which case the 'encapsulation proper' method is to dispatch an event from component1; listen for the event in component1s parent; and execute the function from the event listener.

So, somewhere in headerbar's parent, add the event listener:

```
headerbarInstance.addEventListener('parentDoSomething', onHeaderBarToldMeTo);
```

I'd probably add this in the constructor if an ActionSCript 3 component, or in a preinitialize event handler if an MXML Component.  The 'parent' component will also need the listener function:

```
protected function onHeaderBarToldMeTo(event:Event):void{
  erase();
}
```

When the clicks the button component in headerbar.mxml and this fires off a click event handler inside of headerbar, which needs to dispatch the event, like this:

```
protected function onButtonInheaderbarClick(Event:Event):void{
 dispatchEvent(new Event('parentDoSomething'));
}
```

And everything should magically work.  You may have to bubble the event if the function is not inside a direct child of the parent.

If you don't care about encapsulation, you can also just access the parent directly.  So your header bar component would do this:

```
parent.erase();
```

It's simple and straight forward, and should work, but is considered horribly bad practice from a maintenance stand point.

Comment: Thanks I understand how to do it now if I'm just referencing a functon in another view, however what I forgot to mention is that the erase() is in a drawArea object I instantiate in my main appview. So I need to run the erase() on the object in my other view. Please see my edit. That is what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: @Casey Wylde if 'erase()' is a public method on a child of the view; then once the event bubbles up; instead of erase do "myChild.erase()".  Everything else I said holds true.

Comment: You can also use FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication to access the the top level application and call the function that way; but it is also considered bad from an encapsulation stand point as it provides an external dependency to your component.