# Adobe Flex reference another object

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, adobe

I have a flex 3 datagrid that is in a completely separate container from the object that I am trying to reference it from - i.e. the datagrid is in a vbox, and I am trying to set a property in the datagrid from a popup.

How do I access the datagrid from the popup?
I'd like to do something like:

```
myView.myDatagrid.resizableColumns = false;
```

Using cairngorm as a framework if that is of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to explain your architecture better to get a specific answer.  [This answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244861/flex-executing-a-function-on-another-view/6245009#6245009) as everything I said about running methods on another component, also applies to accessing properties.

One solution for you is to pass the DataGrid instance into the popup as an instance variable; then the PopUp will be able to change the DataGrid's properties easy.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your popup, you need to listen for an event. Then your PopUp needs to dispatch an event that the parent can handle.

```
myPopup.addEventListener(SomeEvent.DISABLE_COLUMNS,disableResize);
```

and then in the parent component

```
public function disableResize(event:SomeEvent):void{
   myDatagrid.resizableColumns = false;
}
```

This assumes a custom event called SomeEvent... you can actually just create a default Flash event and give it a name like

```
 dispatchEvent(new Event("MyDisableResizeEvent"));
```

Assuming you've got a button in your popup:

```
<mx:Button click="{dispatchEvent(new Event('MyDisableResizeEvent'));}" label="Disable Resizing"/>
```